# How to search in database by birthday?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to search by birthday but I can't do it 
and this what I tried:

Class:

```
[Required] 
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)] 
[Display(Name = "Birthdate")] 
[DataType(DataType.Date)] 
public DateTime Birthdate { get; set; }
```

Conditional Statement:

```
else if (searchBy == "Birthdate")
{
    return View(db.Class1.Where(x => x.Birthdate.Equals(Convert.ToDateTime(search)).ToList());
}
```

Comment: is there any error message ?

Comment: please post more to the question to give us the best idea of how to help.. try posting the output, classes, properties, error messages, etc

Comment: what happens if you try `return View(db.Class1.Where(x => x.BirthDate.Date == Convert.ToDateTime(search).Date)).ToList();`?

Comment: Do you really want to search by exact date (including year), or do you "just" want to know who will celebrate a birthday tomorrow?

Comment: search by exact date (including year)

Comment: i try to search with birth date and age and birth date range , i had one prop in entity mode` "[Required] [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)] [Display(Name = "Birthdate")] [DataType(DataType.Date)] public DateTime Birthdate { get; set; }" `
`            else if (searchBy == "Birthdate")
            {
                return View(db.Class1.ToList().Where(x => x.Birthdate.CompareTo(Convert.ToDateTime(search)) || search == null));
            }`

Answer (score 1):

Try splitting up your search date:

```
var day = search.Date;
var month = search.Month;
var year = search.Year;

db.Class1.Where(x => x.Birthdate.Day == day && x.Birthdate.Month == month && x.Birthdate.Year == year).ToList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
db.Class1.Where(x => x.Birthdate.Day == Convert.ToInt32(search)).ToList());
```

Comment: or add this
`search == null`

Comment: Your Question is "How to search in database by birthday?"... do you mean "birthday" or "birthdate" ?

Comment: there r a update from birthday to birthdate 
and add this code so can be null without bugs ` || search == null`

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are storing Date of Birth as a DateTime.  It would be much better if you just stored it as a Date, unless you're actually recording a time of birth!  You can configure Entity Framework to use Date type by [adding a convention](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29152631/163495).

Once you've done that, decorate your Date of Birth field:

```
public class Person {
    //...

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime Birthdate { get; set; }
```

When you've done this, your search will work as you expected, since the time component is no longer stored in the database.

Comment: can i edit in attribute after i insert data in database ?

Comment: `[Required]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Display(Name = "Birthdate")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime Birthdate { get; set; }`

Comment: Yes, you can add this in with existing data.  You need to have the convention from the linked answer in place for this to work.  Once you do this, you'll generate a new migration to change the column data type from datetime to date.

Comment: `[Required]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime Birthdate { get; set; }`
i tried that but still the same porblem

Answer (score -1):

If you want to search by the full date:

```
return View(db.Class1.Where(x => x.Birthdate.Date == Convert.ToDateTime(search).Date)).ToList());
```

Comment: and when i run that " else if (searchBy == "Birthdate")
            {
                return View(db.Class1.ToList().Where(x => (DateTime.Now.Year - x.Birthdate.Year) == Convert.ToInt32(search) || search == null));"
            }
Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: @MuhammadAbuMandor What? you're entire return statement has changed since original post?

Comment: i try to search with birth date and age and birth date range , i had one prop in entity mode "[Required]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Display(Name = "Birthdate")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime Birthdate { get; set; }"
it's my frist time to use stackoverflow so sry for messier

Comment: @MuhammadAbuMandor No problem, please post what you just posted as a comment to me, in your original question post, along with the entire conditional if statement, not just the `else if`

Comment: @MuhammadAbuMandor your return statement needs to be changed to put the `.ToList()` at the end.. so `return View(db.Class1.Where(x => x.Birthdate.CompareTo(Convert.ToDateTime(search)) || search == null).ToList());`

Comment: Error 1 Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'bool'

Comment: @MuhammadAbuMandor have you tried the solution that I posted?

Comment: return View(db.Class1.Where(x => x.Birthdate.CompareTo(Convert.ToDateTime(search)) || search == null).ToList());
i tried this

Comment: @MuhammadAbuMandor try `return View(db.Class1.Where(x => x.Birthdate.Date == Convert.ToDateTime(search).Date)).ToList());`