# ASP.NET MVC Core, How can I set default behaviour of a `DateType.Date` rendered field in entire application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, date

Using ASP.NET MVC Core, How can I set default behaviour of a `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` rendered field?

I would like to avoid the HTML5 '' yet due some browser and locales incompatibility.

The default ASP.NET MVC core behaviour to `<input asp-for"MyProperty" >` is to add `type="date"` and set formatting to `yyyy-MM-dd`.

The solution I found is to set `type="text"` inside the `input` tag and then add the `DisplayFormat` data annotation to each Property, like.. `<input asp-for"MyProperty" type="text">`

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime created_date { get; set; }
```

However I do have several date fields. I would like to do not make my ViewModel so verbose adding this data annotation to each Property.

Is there a way to set the default behaviour of a Date field in entire application?

Comment: If you do not want `type="date"` then remove `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` (the only purpose of the attribute is to add `type="date"`),

Comment: Don't the `DateType.Date`sets the database to store the object as `Date` instead of a `DateTime` ? That is why I'm doing this.

Comment: Do you mean for EF code first? (in which case its `[Column(TypeName="Date")]`) - refer [Entity Framework Code First Date field creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658216/entity-framework-code-first-date-field-creation)

Comment: Yes ! EF code first. You're telling me that the `DateType.Date` is not enought to enforce the migration to create the data as `Date` instead of `DateTime`, and I must add the `[Column(TypeName="Date")]` annotation also to enforce this requirement?

Comment: Or one of the other options in the answers to that question.

Comment: @StephenMuecke removing `DataType(DataType.Date)` don't solve the problem, the field still as date, in fact still as `type="datetime-local"`

Comment: What I mean is `DataType(DataType.Date)` will add `type="date"` - if you do not want that then remove it. (you can always add `type="text"`, or use `[DataType(DataType.Text)]`